# How to store text input from UITextField as variable and display it in a UILabel in a different View using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Basically what the title says. I have a UITextField that a user can enter text into. I also have a countdown timer. Once the countdown timer reaches 0 (or the user stops the timer early by pressing the Done button), I want my app to capture what was written in the UITextField and display it using a UILabel, **but** on another View. How do I go about doing this?

Extra information: Once the timer reaches 0, I have a UIAlert popup that has a Continue button. By pressing this button, it advances to the next ViewController. I already have done what I want to do but on the same ViewController. i.e. I have UITextField and UILabel **in the same ViewController** and I am able to make the label update to what a user has typed at the press of a button. Now, I'd like to move that UILabel to another ViewController and still have it update. Here is some sample code of how I'm currently doing it, with the UILabel in the same ViewController as the UITextField:

```
@IBOutlet var singleText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var singleFinalText: UILabel!
@IBAction func singlePrev(sender: UIButton) {
    singleFinalText.text = singleText!.text
}
```

Comment: Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: what is another view? how r u presenting it ? R  u using segues ?Is it another view or another view controller ?

Comment: @Cristik Once the timer reaches 0, I have a UIAlert popup that has a Continue button. By pressing this button, it advances to the next ViewController. I wish I could paste my code, but funnily enough it is too long to fit into this comment but if there is a way to upload screenshots, please let me know - I'd be glad to. I already have done what I want to do **but on the same ViewController**. i.e. I have UITextField and UILabel in the same ViewController and I am able to make the label update to what a user has typed at the press of a button. Now, I'd like to move that UILabel to another View

Comment: @Mr.T I meant another ViewController. I am not using segues. I believe I have done it programatically. I am not entirely sure - I'm new to Swift and coding in general as I said in my first question (which was about how to advance to the next ViewController by pressing a button in a UIAlert) so I'm sorry that I couldn't be more specific :/

Comment: @ryanbangras please update your question with these details comments are harder to read

Comment: The IBOutlet/IBActions suggest you _are_ using Storyboards. It's difficult for anyone to give a good, specific answer if you don't have a good, specific question.

Comment: @StephenDarlington I'm sorry that I wasn't being specific in my question. I guess I was just really excited to want to do this that I forgot certain things. Please forgive me, but also please help me by telling me if there is any more information I have to give to get an answer!

Comment: did u solve ur issue ? there are many answers out there on presenting a viw controller programamtically on a button click!!!

Comment: @Mr.T unfortunately, no. My question was not about presenting ViewControllers programmatically - I believe I've already done that. My question was _how do I store whatever a user has typed into a UITextField on ViewControllerA and then display that same text in a UILabel thats in my programmatically created ViewControllerB_

Comment: I suggest you to go through this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.

For argument, say I have two view controllers ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB.

To pass the value from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB, follow the steps mentioned here.

1. Create a variable in ViewControllerB.swift

   ```
   var labelString: String?
   ```
2. After this, go to ViewControllerA.swift and go to prepareForSegue Method

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
   {
      if segue.identifier == "YOURSEGUENAME" //Defined in storyboard
      {
          let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerB
          viewController.labelString = self.singleText.text // set the textfield text here
      }

   }
   ```
3. Now, go to ViewControllerB.swift and go to viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method and set the label text

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() 
   {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.YOURLABELNAME.text = labelString // set your label text here
   }
   ```